# OpenAm invalid cookie domain

Tags: openam

Can some one help me out with the invalid cookie domain in openAM, as I am new to openAM and configuring it first time.

when I run openAM war file from the tomcat installed in my windows PC,I am able to configure default user, but I get "invalid cookie domain" for the same when I try to create default user by running openAM from linux.

Comment: apperently openam has an issue with extracting cookiedomain. Due to proxy restrictions I could not use the www|openam.example.com and had to use another domain, the cookie domain failed to get created. When using `custom configuration` instead of the `default configuration` promoted in the getting-started guide, you can manually set the cookie domain (don't forget the padding dot).

Answer (score 8):

A common newbie problem in OpenAM is attempting installation using `localhost` instead of a proper FQDN.

OpenAM needs proper cookie domains to function correctly. A good strategy for development is to create a local `/etc/hosts` entry (or the Windows equivalent) that looks something like this:

```
127.0.0.1 openam.example.com
```

When you install OpenAM, use `openam.example.com` as the host, and `example.com` as the cookie domain.

Comment: While going through setup, it does not allow me to change the hostname. It's a read-only field.

Comment: The installer will use the domain name from the browser that you use to access openam.  For example,  do NOT use  http://localhost/openam. Use the FQDN (http://www.example.com/openam)

Comment: Ah okay, it wasn't clear from the answer this was from the context of a browser. Thanks!

Comment: I did this change in windows 10 machine, but after setting the openam configuration, openam hangs in login page. But it doesnt hange for localhost configuration. Any clue?

Answer (score 3):

What I have found is that "not so common" domain names (names other than example.com, .net, .org, etc) do not behave well with openam.

Using openam version 11, I set up the hosts file with my machine's fqdn (fully qualified domain name), which is in a domain called something like "projectname.local".

When I deploy openam and try to create default configurations, it fails immediately saying something like "invalid cookie domain".

If I try to circumvent this by creating a new configuration, I see right away that openam thinks my domain is called ".local" instead of "projectname.local" in one of the early configuration forms.

It's only when I change the domain name in hosts to something like "example.com" (like the getting started guide tells you to) that default configuration runs ok.

Otherwise, i couldn't get it to work.

Comment: The installer uses the Mozilla public suffix list library to validate and understand DNS names. If your not so common domain names are not valid this will cause issues.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is well documented in [OpenAM installation guide](http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/11.0.0/install-guide/#prepare-networking):

> 1.1. Preparing a Fully-Qualified Domain Name OpenAM requires that you provide the fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) when you configure it.
>   Before you set up OpenAM, be sure that your system has an FQDN such as
>   openam.example.com. For evaluation purposes, you can give your system
>   an alias using the `/etc/hosts` file on UNIX systems or
>   `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows. For deployment,
>   make sure the FQDN is properly assigned for example using DNS.
>
> Do not use the localhost domain for OpenAM, not even for testing
>   purposes. OpenAM relies on browser cookies, which are returned based
>   on domain name. Furthermore, use a domain name that contains at least
>   2 . (dot) characters, such openam.example.com

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the OpenAM installation documentation. OpenAM requires you to provide a Fully-Qualified-Domain-Name (FQDN). Now, if your FQDN is of format `dev-app.server.com` (notice the DASH) OpenAM server may read that incorrectly and set your cookie domain to a wrong value. You can check this by simply visiting System > Platform > Global Attributes > Cookie Domains. For a FQDN `dev-app.server.com` ensure the cookie domain is set to `.server.com`

Answer (score 1):

When I first installed OpenAM I also faced this issue and found this topic here.

In my case, the error happened to occur when using the "*Create Default Configuration*" option (as shown on this video - http://forgerock.com/openam-11-0-two-minute-install/).

When I switch to the second option (*Create New Configuration*), I could see what was the reason for this issue:

The hostname was set to: "**192.168.0.52:8080**". The OpenAM Configurator automatically selected "**.52**" as the cookie domain. After changing it to the complete IP Address "**192.168.0.52**", the configurator was now able to successfully complete the installation.

Maybe it is not suitable for production use, but for my evaluation purposes this was enough. Hope it helps someone else out there.

Comment: As explained above, you can not use IP addresses. You must use proper DNS names.

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell which cookie domain you specified , so it's impossible to tell why OpenAM complains. However it's a good idea to make yourself familiar with 'HTTP state management mechanism' (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265). The question is not really related to OpenAM though.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is your case, but keep in mind that recent versions of Tomcat 8 (9?) seem to have changed something in their cookies, and now it will not work with cookiedomain starting with a dot (".example.com") as OpenAm examples suggests.

But that will happen after correct installation, and the later login will fail.

See 
https://forgerock.org/topic/login-page-not-loading-after-setup/
and others

Answer (score 0):

It needs FDQN. Eg. openam.server1.com / openam.server2.com

You can configure multiple cookie domains from 
System -> Platform -> Global Attributes -> Cookie Domains

Example: Add server1 and server2 here.

A cookie generated for server1 will not be valid in server2. 
There is an option for configuring multiple domains.